# Getting data from an XML document using DOM in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I'm trying to parse an XML file using DOM, but at the end only the last entry is output several times (in a loop). Tell me, please, what is the problem? (I'm a beginner in Java)

XML with approximately the following content:

```
<channel>
    <title>www.google.com</title>
    <item>
        <title>www.youtube.com</title>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>play.google.com</title>
    </item>
    ...
</channel>
```

Java Code:

```
    Node item = null;
    NodeList channelList = document.getElementsByTagName("channel");
    for (int i = 0; i < channelList.getLength(); i++){

        if (channelList.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
            
            NodeList channelListChild = channelList.item(i).getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < channelListChild.getLength(); j++){
                if (channelListChild.item(j).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){

                    switch (channelListChild.item(j).getNodeName()){
                        case "title":{
                            String title = channelListChild.item(j).getTextContent();
                            System.out.println(title);
                            break;
                        }
                        case "item":{
                            item = channelListChild.item(j);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (item == null){
        return;
    }

    String title = null;
    NodeList itemList = item.getChildNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.getLength(); i++){
        if (itemList.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){

            switch (itemList.item(i).getNodeName()){
                case "title":{
                    title = itemList.item(i).getTextContent();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(title);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the variable "item" to each item in turn in your loop, and its value on exit is therefore the last `item` element encountered.

You're not alone in using Java and DOM for this kind of application; it's a popular combination. But it's approaching 25 years old, and there are many better choices available. Even if it has to be Java, there are other APIs such as JDOM2 and XOM that are much friendlier to use.

Saxon's tree navigation API (inspired by LINQ in the C# world) would look something like this:

```
XdmNode channel = document.getOutermostElement();
String title = channel.select(child("title")).asString();
System.out.println(title);
channel.select(child("item")).forEach(item -> {
   String subtitle = item.select("title").asString();
   System.out.println(subtitle);
}
```

which is a fraction of the length of the equivalent DOM code.

[Disclaimer: Saxon is my company's product]